# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx, on apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I am using curl to scrape data from other website, i am running on apache server, then why i am getting this error

### 504 Gateway Time-out

#### nginx

I mean what does nginx mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from the website you are trying to crawl, not on the server you are running apache.

Maybe your scraper is very aggressive and you DOS (Denial Of Service) the target website by mistake. Also there might be some protection in place in the target website which gives you back this error.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was getting very confused, Btw what does "dos the website" means?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - DOS means Denial Of Service attack, when you make a system not available by some of your actions (sometimes not malicious).

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to handle this error via php curl, it halts the whole script

Comment: You should ask on stackoverflow - probably somebody will be able to provide a solution.